# Android: How to set time from time picker in two different EditText fields (start/end)?

Tags: android, events, dialog, timepicker

I am trying to get the time when the user clicks on the `EditText` StartTime and EndTime. The problem is that I don't know how to distinguish the `EditText`s at the `TimePickerFragment`. Any help, please?

```
public void initializeTime () {
    startTimeEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.startTimeEditText);
    startTimeEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Initialize a new time picker dialog fragment
            DialogFragment dFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
            // Show the time picker dialog fragment
            dFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"TimePicker");
        }
    });

    endTimeEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.endTimeEditText);
    endTimeEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Initialize a new time picker dialog fragment
            DialogFragment dFragment = new TimePickerFragment();

            // Show the time picker dialog fragment
            dFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"TimePicker");
        }
    });
}
```

`TimePickerFragment.java`:

```
@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    // Do something with the time chosen by the user
    EditText startTimeEditText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.startTimeEditText);
    EditText endTimeEditText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.endTimeEditText);
    flag = getArguments().getString("Flag");
    Log.v(TAG,flag);

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Toast"+flag, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    if (startTimeEditText.isActivated()){
        startTimeEditText.setText(String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + ":" + String.valueOf(minute));
    }
    else if (endTimeEditText.isActivated()){
        endTimeEditText.setText(String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + ":" + String.valueOf(minute));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`TimePickerFragment` should not mess with the layout of the rest of the `Activity`: the best way here is to pass a listener to the `TimePickerFragment`. Take a look at `TimePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(...)`, I know it's not a `Fragment`, but the idea is the same.

Another solution is to use an event bus (for example including the [EventBus library](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)) and posting a new event when the user select a date: in this way any component of your app can subscribe to this event and act accordingly.